# Having some trouble with assignment

Tags: python

I need to make some functions that perform basic algebraic operations and a couple of other things on quaternions(these are basically complex numbers of the form a + x*i + y*j + z*k). I first created a class which contain some attributes, and whenever i create an instance with it I get a quaternion. However, when I tried implementing the functions I mentioned before I keep getting error messages. Anyway, here is my code in its full:

```
from math import *
class Quaternion(object):
    def __init__(self, re, xc, yc, zc):
        self.a = re
        self.x = xc
        self.y = yc
        self.z = zc

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a) + "+" + str(self.x) + "i" + "+" + str(self.y) + "j" + "+" + str(self.z) + "k"

    def add(self, q):
        self.a = self.a + q.a
        self.x = self.x + q.x
        self.y = self.y + q.y
        self.z = self.z + q.z

    def mul(self, q):
        self.a = self.a*q.a - self.x*q.x - self.y*q.y - self.z*q.z
        self.x = self.a*q.x + self.x*q.a + self.y*q.z - self.z*q.y
        self.y = self.a*q.y + self.y*q.a + self.z*q.x - self.x*q.z
        self.z = self.a*q.z + self.z*q.a + self.x*q.y - self.y*q.x

    def conjugate(self):
        self.a = self.a
        self.x = -1 * self.x
        self.y = -1 * self.y
        self.z = -1 * self.z

    def norm(self):
        return sqrt((self.a)**2+(self.x)**2+(self.y)**2+(self.z)**2)

    def reciprocal(self):
        p1 = self.conjugate()
        self.a = p1.a * (1/(self.norm())**2)
        self.x = p1.x * (1/(self.norm())**2)
        self.y = p1.y * (1/(self.norm())**2)
        self.z = p1.z * (1/(self.norm())**2)

def main():
    p = Quaternion(2, 0, -3, 0)
    q = Quaternion(0, 1, 1, -2)
    print "p =", p
    print "q =", q
    print "p + q =", p.add(q)
    print "p * q =", p.mul(q)
    print "conjugate of p is", p.conjugate()
    print "norm of p is", p.norm()
    print "reciprocal of p is", p.reciprocal()
    print "p x reciprocal(p) =", p.mul(p.reciprocal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, whenever I run the module(so it then executes the commands under the main function), I get this:

```
p = 2+0i+-3j+0k
q = 0+1i+1j+-2k
p + q = None
p * q = None
conjugate of p is None
norm of p is 9.11043357914
reciprocal of p is
```

The only thing it does right is printing out the two quaternions p and q, but none of the other functions/methods seem to be working properly(the norm does give a value, but it isnt the right one for some reason).

Before I forget, let me quickly say what each functions needs to do:

add(self, q) needs to add 2 quaternions together.
mul(self, q) needs to multiply 2 quaternions.
conjugate(self) needs to transform a given quaternion a + x*i + y*j + z*k into this form: a - x*i - y*j - z*k.
norm(self) and reciprocal(self) need to respectively return the norm and reciprocal of the quaternion

Comment: `add()` doesn't return a value, which is why it prints `None`.  Instead, `p.add(q)` modifies `p` in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing the math correctly in principle, but you are not returning a new object where you should be.

For example, let's look at `add()`. When you sum two objects, you are expecting the return value to be a third object of the same type, which you are printing. Your `add()` function does not return anything (in Python this is equivalent to returning `None`), and instead unexpectedly modifies the object it is called on. Instead, do this:

```
def add(self, q):
    return Quaternion(self.a + q.a,
                      self.x + q.x,
                      self.y + q.y,
                      self.z + q.z)
```

Do the same for the other methods. If you want to use `+` and `*` operators in your code, change the method names to `__add__` and `__mul__`. To do in-place addition and multiplication using `+=` and `*=` operators, sort of like your current methods are doing, rename the current methods to `__iadd__` and `__imul__`, but don't forget to return `self` at the end.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I tried implementing the add function you suggested, but running the module now gives me the following error:TypeError: add() takes no arguments (2 given). Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to copy the function arguments. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You get the None values because you did not specify a return value. Add a

```
return self
```

at the end of add, mul, conjugate and reciprocal. (If it is intended that these methods change the value of p, and do not just compute a new Quaternion while leaving p untouched.)